# How to request with method get with axios. Send uid, client and token

Tags: reactjs, get, axios, httprequest, redux-saga

I'm trying to get data from an API, but it needs me to send -> (client - uid and token information). How do I do this using redux-sagas and axios? BUT it works on the postman.

[image]

SAGAS.TS

```
export function* getListTasks({payload}) {
  try {

    const resp = yield call(api.get, 'enterprises', {headers: {
      client: "nyzcig9rTLqAKeHLmoL4LQ",
      'access-token': "Ds23VSssxu2mDafOIHqmcg",
      uid: "testeapple@company.com.br"
    }});

    console.log(payload)

    //yield put(setListCompanys(resp.data));
  } catch (err) {
    Alert.alert(
      'ERROR REUQEST',
      'ERROR: '+err,

    );
  }
}
```

Return Error: [Error: Request failed with status code 401]

Comment: What currently isn't working with your sagas.ts? If there is an error can you include it?

Comment: it returns error 401, I don't know how to make this request with these parameters. [Error: Request failed with status code 401]

Comment: If it's working in postman but not in code, check out CORS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, I was making the request wrongly, follow the code: (I hope it helps someone)

```
export function* signIn({payload}) {
  try {
   const {email, password} = payload;

   const response = yield call(api.post, 'users/auth/sign_in', {
   email,
   password,
 });

 const login = {
   token: response.headers['access-token'],
   uid: response.headers.uid,
   client: response.headers.client,
 };

 if (login) {
   api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${login.token}`;
   api.defaults.headers['access-token'] = login.token;
   api.defaults.headers['uid'] = login.uid;
   api.defaults.headers['client'] = login.client;
 }

 yield put(signInSuccess(login, response.data));
 } catch (err) {
   Alert.alert(
    'Falha na autenticação',
   'Houve um erro no login, verifique seus dados: ' + err,
 );
 yield put(signFailure());
 }
}
```